# Query pancake swap staking contract

Tags: web3js, blockchain, bsc, pancakeswap, api

I've been trying to find information on how to query pancakeswap's staking contract for some time now, and I've unfortunately been unsuccessful this far.
I was wondering if anyone would be so kind as to provide some pointers in a way that I could achieve this?

What I'm looking for is a way to obtain information about staked Cake from a specific contract and/or wallet address, including any pending/unclaimed rewards.
I apologise if this is an obvious question, but as a junior dev who's experience is almost entirely outside of blockchain and crypto, I'm at a loss as to where I should look.

This is for a personal project, with the ambition of familiarising myself with blockchain, and contract exploration.

Thanks in advance for any replies and pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The staking pool for Cake token is [here](https://bscscan.com/address/0x45c54210128a065de780C4B0Df3d16664f7f859e). There is a tab named "contract", you can view the source code there.

In the contract tab, there are two more sections. You can send functions to the contract address using methods under `read contract` and `write contract`. `Read contract` calls don't cost any gas.

One of the functions is called `userInfo`, fill in the user's address you will probably get what you need.

Welcome to the crypto. Please remember to verify whatever I said here. Don't give your trust to anybody on the Internet.